# Breadth First Traversal of NLTK Tree

Tags: python, tree, nltk

I am trying to do breadth first traversal on NLTK tree. But while calling subtrees method on a current node it dosen't give me subtree but the existing node itself.

```
def traverseTree(tree):
    queue = [tree]
    visited = set(tree.label())

    while queue:
        node = queue.pop(0)

        for neighbor in node.subtrees():
            if neighbor.label() not in visited:
                queue.append(neighbor)
                visited.add(neighbor.label())

    return visited
```

Can anyone please tell how do bfs on nltk tree ?

```
def bfs(tree, children=iter, maxdepth=-1):
    queue = deque([(tree, 0)])

    while queue:
        node, depth = queue.popleft()
        yield node

        if depth != maxdepth:
            try:
                queue.extend((c, depth + 1) for c in children(node))
            except TypeError:
                pass
```

I am unable to call this default bfs implementation even after adding it to my code.

Comment: http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.html#nltk.util.breadth_first ?

Comment: @alvas i implemented the given default implementation but its not callable even after passing required parameters. Don't know where i am going wrong..

Comment: Can you show the input tree? Perhaps the input tree is not well-formed, e.g. orphaned branch.